# Strange login form I didn't create gets shown

Tags: login, joomla-3.5, registration

So I'm working on a website right now (duh) and I have a registration/login form when I click on the website. Logging in and stuff works fine, but I can for the love of god not find from where it comes. I usually use a login module, and if I activate it, both get shown and both work, but for the login module I can change options (for example where the user gets directed to when he logs in). I have, so far, not found anything about this mystery, except that it might be a standard from my template or something (Have I mentioned I'm fairly new to joomla?).

So here is a picture of how it looks with the module activated. The top part where it says "Login" up to the red line is my module, the bottom part is the mysterious login that just popped up out of nowhere (and I've checked **everything** three times, I even let a colleague check everything once and he didn't find anything either. Also, sorry because its german and not in english).

[image]

I either need to know how to change options for the bottom login form to make it redirect where I want it to go, or how to get rid of it completely and let my module take over. If you need any other information feel free to ask, I will happily provide anything that might help you help ... me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second login page is default Joomla login view. If you want to change login redirect page is follow this steps. However, I will suggest you don't publish login module on this view.

1. Navigate to Menus->your menu->Add New Menu Item

[image]

2. Enter a Menu Title and Select the Menu Item Type
   [image]

[image]

3. Now select login redirection config
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

On this page you see 2 login forms. The one of them you say you know from where it's coming from and it's your login module that you have chosen to display as per your desire.

Well, the other login form as we see it in the screenshot you have posted, is coming from the core **com_users** component and this is because you are currently loading this component's login view.

Just note your URL on that page: `../localhost/joomla/index.php/component/users/?view=login`

If you navigate back to your home page `../localhost/joomla/index.php` the second login form should go away.

Just to give you some further help as of why you got there:

There can be various reasons for Joomla to redirect you to its core login 
form page, depending on the whole website setup.

The most common though are these:

1. Likely you clicked on a content item that requires you to be registered member to see it - In this case Joomla will take you to its core component login form.
2. Maybe you just logged out, (or your session timed-out) and Joomla is configured to redirect you back to the login form after logout.
3. A plugin or other extension may forcing redirection to the login form.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer, it helped me figure out why it happens and I appreciate every bit of help I can get. But my problem is only solved halfway with the "why", hence if I try to load the normal index.php it redirects me to the login=view. Indeed do I have some modules that can only be watched while registered, but I need them for my website to work properly and thats how they should be. I would like to know how to either force it to go to index.php or disable the redirection to view=login completely. 

Thanks in advance

Comment: @LordScrat - ok this is some new info - it's possible that you have set your home page (home menu item) to an access level that requires login. Check this at first place. If it;s not on the menu item, then there is something else that forces this, either an extension or some code somewhere, but in this case it would be harder to get much more help without access to the issue.

Comment: I've solved it with the answer from aMoL Thite, but thanks to your explanation I understood why it did that, so thank you a lot.